# wrap a x86 C dll symbols into nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js, node-gyp

I have a dll compiled with mingw gcc toolchain (32bits). I want to wrap a symbol into a javascript function. I did the following code :

binding.gyp

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "hellomod",
            "sources": [ "hellomod.cc" ],
            "include_dirs": [
                "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
            ],
            "libraries": [
                "C:\\juan\\repos\\sandbox\\node\\dll_module\\hello_lib\\hello.lib"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

hellomod.cc

```
#include <nan.h>

extern "C" {
    __declspec( dllimport ) void hello(char *name);
}

using namespace v8;

NAN_METHOD(Method) {
    NanScope();
    hello("Juan");
    NanReturnValue(String::New("Hello world"));
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
    exports->Set(NanSymbol("hello"), FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(hellomod, Init)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Mon premier package dll",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Juan",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "nan": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "gypfile": true
}
```

When I do the command `node-gyp rebuild` I get the following error :

```
hellomod.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_hello [c:\juan\r
epos\sandbox\node\dll_module\hello\build\hellomod.vcxproj]
c:\juan\repos\sandbox\node\dll_module\hello\build\Release\hellomod.node : fatal
 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [c:\juan\repos\sandbox\node\dll_module\h
ello\build\hellomod.vcxproj]
```

Note: The project works well on a windows xp 32bits with visual studio 2010, and not on windows 7.1 with visual studio 2012. You can have a look at https://github.com/JuanTrochez/sandbox/tree/master/node/dll_module for the exact code.
Thanks.